# How to use HttpClient in ScriptEditor SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to do some Http request. I think it's easy to do it using HttpClient. But it's not working in ScriptEditor SSIS.
My ScriptEditor's Framework is .Net Framework 4.5. and my SSDT is 2017. Even I change it to .Net Framework 4.6.1, it's still not working.

I also have tried it by creating a normal project. it's not working either. But it's working when changing framework to .Net Framework 4.6.1.

By the way, my coding is as below.

```
 public async static Task<bool> CheckUserId()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("URL");

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //... 200 OK

                var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved by the link below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4308a238-b774-42c2-b86d-853fc3ec22f6/ssis-package-c-script-task-to-make-https-call-using-httpclient?forum=sqlintegrationservices&prof=required